# Migrating three derby databases to one MySQL database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, derby, database-migration

We've got a Spring Hibernate, Apache Derby (Database) Java application running on Jetty server.

**Problem**

We've got 3 Apache Derby databases (DB1, DB2,DB3) that we need to migration in one MySQL database.

UPDATE: DB1, DB2, DB3 have the same schema with different data.

**Foreign key constrains**

The database schema currently do not have foreign key restrictions at the database level but we do have foreign key constraints at Application level. We have about a 100 tables to migrate into one Apache Derby Database and then move it to a MySQL database with some tables having records over 10 million.

**Solutions**

1. We were thinking of merging DB1 and DB3 into DB2 first. DB2 is largest so we are thinking of using that as the base database and then moving merged DB2 to MySQL database. Using Hibernate I can write a program that will create 2 session factories to DB1 and DB2 first and push data from DB1 to DB2 creating records in a new temporary table named NEW_IDS with the following columns.

   NEW_ID - ID of the new record added
   OLD_ID - ID of the record
   TABLE_NAME - Name of the table.

   And when I come across a table which has foreign key constraints I can look up NEW_IDS table to find the NEW_ID for the OLD_ID for that table and persisting the Hibernate Entity setting the new ids into DB2.
2. Move each Apache Derby database to MySQL database and have 3 MySQL databases and then use tool like Redgate Data Compare to merge the data because by reading the documentation it looks like they don't support Data compare for Apache Derby but only SQL servers and Oracle. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Question**

Can you please tell us if you have been in a similar situation and what problems did you face  and If you see any problems with above two approaches or are there any other approach you think would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I faced the same kind off situation where I want to make one DB from 5 small DBs. First tell us all DBs (DB1,DB2,DB3) having different tables or same? The problem I faced is same primary keys in all DBs. In my case all 5 DBs having same tables.

For Eg.

DB1 having table Person where 1 to 10k primary keys are used

DB2 again having Person table with 1 to 6k primary keys

so merging will be difficult.

Comment: I don't the exact scenario in your case whatever I faced I just shared.

Comment: All the databases have the same schema.

Comment: @CMR Then don't you think primary key will be the problem as I described in answer? And I think idea NEW_ID & OLD_ID will work but will become overhead on CRUD

Comment: The was to have NEW_IDS table as just a temporary table until all the data from the 3 databases have migrated and our system has moved to one MySQL database. The NEW_IDS table won't be in production.

Comment: @CMR This sounds nice but this will be very long process as you said some tables are having records over 10 million. Lets see what other suggestions will come forward.

Comment: I am facing same problem but database is Mysql and all the databases having same tables structure